# Use same random variable in all threads

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I've got test plan :

Thread groups ( users 3, loop 2)
Random Variable
HTTP Request

I want variable to be changed only per loop, so under each iteration all three threads should send same value.

So I want something like this :

request where random var = X

request where random var = X

request where random var = X

request where random var = Y

request where random var = Y

request where random var = Y

I tried a lot of workounds but can't find proper solution.

P.S. I don't want to read variables from file. I need to generate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter whatever you "want" the best option would be pre-generating random values somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) and writing it to the file and then using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in the "main" Thread Group to read the values.

However if this is still not something you "want" here is yet another "workaround", hopefully it's "proper" enough for you:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which you "want" to parameterize with the random variable
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (props.get('foo_' + vars.getIteration()) != null {
       props.put('foo_' + vars.getIteration(), org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 100))
   }
   ```
3. Refer the "generated" random value using the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) where required:

   ```
   ${__groovy(props.get('foo_' + vars.getIteration()),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I've marked that as an answer. I couldn't find any other solution. I've run tests  two ways : 

1. As you said I've created .csv file and read variables from there.

2. I've added Counter element, which is same for all threads and is updated once per iteration